# for loop help and sprite addition

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have two questions. what I am 
trying to do is every time I shoot a enemy/vine it should be 
removed and a explosion should occur. the removal works perfect
but the sprite is not called to explode

1. What's this in the for loop `#sections[sectInt]["vines"]` ? 
      Are they parent/ child references? Can someone break this
      down to the letter even telling me what the `#` is?
2. How can I use my explosion sprite after each vine is destroyed?
      I am having a difficult time figuring out how to call every x and y 
      vine in the for loop to explode when removed.

Code:

```
local sections = require("sectionData")

local lastSection = 0
function createSection()
    --Create a random number. If its eqaul to the last one, random it again.
    local sectInt = mR(1,#sections)
    if sectInt == lastSection then sectInt = mR(1,#sections) end
    lastSection = sectInt

    --Get a random section from the sectionData file and then
    --Loop through creating everything with the right properties.
    local i
    -- the random creation of vines throughout the screen
    for i=1, #sections[sectInt]["vines"] do
        local object = sections[sectInt]["vines"][i]
        local vine = display.newImageRect(objectGroup, "images/vine"..object["type"]..".png", object["widthHeight"][1], object["widthHeight"][2])
        vine.x = object["position"][1]+(480*object["screen"]); vine.y = object["position"][2]; vine.name = "vine"


        local rad = (vine.width*0.5)-8; local height = (vine.height*0.5)-8
        local physicsShape = { -rad, -height, rad, -height, rad, height, -rad, height }
        physics.addBody( vine, "static", { isSensor = true, shape = physicsShape } )
    end
end

-- explosion sprite
options1 = 
{
    width = 96, height = 96,
    numFrames = 16,
    sheetContentWidth = 480,
    sheetContentHeight = 384
}
playerSheet1 = graphics.newImageSheet( "images/explosion.png", options1)
playerSprite1 = { 
    {name="explosion", start=1, count=16, time = 400, loopCount = 1 },
}

explode = display.newSprite(playerSheet1, playerSprite1)
explode.anchorX = 0.5
explode.anchorY = 1
--player:setReferencePoint(display.BottomCenterReferencePoint)

-- i want to reference the for loop position if each vine so it plays sprite when they are removed
explode.x = "vine.x" ; explode.y = "vine .y"
explode.name = "explode"
explode.position=1
extraGroup:insert(explode)
```

Comment: `#` is [table length](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5).

Comment: thanks Etan for your reply

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking with your second question.

Comment: i hope i can clear it up, every vine in the for loop has its respective x and y coordinate, vine.x and vine.y. there are many of them, i want to know how can i place  explode.x = vine.x and explode.y = vine.y, so it plays the explosion sprite on every vine in the for loop. thanks again Etan.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What's this in the for loop #sections[sectInt]["vines"] ? Are they parent/ child references? Can someone break this down to the letter even telling me what the # is?

As I said in my comment the `#` is [table length](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5).

The loop is looping over each bit of "vine" data in the selected segment data (whatever that means exactly in terms of the game) and then creates the objects for those vines.

Answer (score 0):

When it's time to make your vine explode, you play the sprite. If you want to explode every vine, you would have something like:

```
sheetOptions = 
{
    width = 96, height = 96,
    numFrames = 16,
    sheetContentWidth = 480,
    sheetContentHeight = 384
}
playerSheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "images/explosion.png", sheetOptions)
spriteSequence = { 
    {name="explosion", start=1, count=16, time = 400, loopCount = 1 },
}

for i, vine in ipairs(objectGroup) do
    local explode = display.newSprite(playerSheet, spriteSequence)
    explode.anchorX = 0.5
    explode.anchorY = 1
    explode.x = vine.x
    explode.y = vine.y
    explode.name = "explode"
    explode.position=1
    explode:play()

    extraGroup:insert(explode)
end
```

Note: not tested, let me know of if any issues you can't resolve.

Comment: thanks Schollii, i have been trying to use your method which i think should be working but it runs a error, "attempt to index field '?' (nil value). i think it cannot find vine since vine is local to the for loop. some help if you can please.

Comment: @user3298518 always indicate clearly which line is at fault, and copy the full error message (don't need full stack but full top-level message). I was assuming that `sections[sectInt]["vines"]` was a table of `vine` display objects but I see upon looking more closely at your code that you create a vine based on each of those `sections[sectInt]["vines"]` objects and put it in `objectGroup`, so I've updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

ok so, this is what i did to get my object to have a explosion, for anybody that is having the same issue.

```
function isShot( event )
           print('shot!!!')
        if (event.other.class == "enemy") then
            if (event.other.name == "limitLine") then  
                event.target:doRemove() --remove bullet if hits the limitLine

            elseif (event.other.name == "vine") then    

                event.other:doRemove()  
                spriteExplode(event.other.x, event.other.y) -- this function calls itself & runs the sprite

                if event.other.name == "vine" then
                    if event.other.name == "explode" then
                        event.other:doRemove()  --this removes the explosion sprite
                    end
               end                  
            end 
            -- remove the bullet & explosion sprite
            timer.performWithDelay( 5000, function(event) explode:doRemove(); end, 1 )
            event.target:doRemove()
       end
    return true
end

function spriteExplode( x, y)

        explode.isVisible = true
        explode:play()
        print("play explode")

        if (x and y) then   -- this is the code that keeps my sprite updating upon removal of vine
            explode.x, explode.y = x, y
        end

        function explode:doRemove(event)
            timer.performWithDelay(
                        1,
                            function(event)
                                display.remove(self)
                                self= nil
                            end,
                    1 )
        end


end
```

i added the isShot function eventListener inside of the Bullet function 
 bullet:addEventListener("collision", isShot) & a bullet:doRemove function is inside the bullet function as well.
hope this helps.